# showAndWait() with animation, using Platform.runlater() gives different behaviour

Tags: animation, javafx, timer

when I don't use animation and have stage.showAndWait() it does the correct behaviour(I get true from a method when yes button is clicked)
But I want to use the anim therefore I do the workaround with

```
Platform.runLater(()-> {
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.showAndWait();
                }
```

but this time even before clicking any button the value is false and I get no value from the button.

So this is my method displaying a confirmdialogbox. I want to restart the game if yes button is clicked and exit the program if no.

```
public boolean display(String title, String message) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader confirmViewLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../main/ConfirmDialogBoxView.fxml"));
        confirmViewLoader.load();
        ConfirmDialogBoxController confirmDialogBoxController = confirmViewLoader.getController();
        confirmDialogBoxController.setConfirmLabelText(message);
        Parent root = confirmViewLoader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(title);

        Platform.runLater(()-> {
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.showAndWait();
                }
        );
        return confirmDialogBoxController.getBtnChoice();
    }
```

and here the part where checking if the game is ended

```
...

TranslateTransition animation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.25), disc);  ///// Animation
        animation.setToY(row * (TILE_SIZE + 5) + TILE_SIZE / 4);

        if (checkConnections(column, currentRow)) {         
            gameOver();
        }else{
            playerRed = !playerRed;
        }

        animation.play();
    }
```

in my confirmdialogboxcontroller:

```
public boolean getBtnChoice(){
        return answer;
    }
@FXML
    public void yesButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        answer = true;
        stage = (Stage) yesButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();

    }

    @FXML
    public void noButtonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        answer = false;
        Stage confirmWindow = (Stage) noButton.getScene().getWindow();
        confirmWindow.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: The call to `Platform.runLater` immediately returns. The `Runnable` will not be executed until some time later, after the FX thread has finished what it's currently doing. So your `showAndWait()` call is executing some time after `display` returns. Why are you using `runLater` in the first place? It'll be difficult to help you without understanding what you're actually trying to do—please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Slaw I assume the `display` method is called from the animation preventing directly calling `showAndWait`, see the documentation: *"`IllegalStateException` - if this method is called during animation or layout processing."*

Comment: @fabian That's my assumption as well, but the code doesn't show that (unless I missed something).

Comment: I am using runlater because I get an error that showandwait() can't be used with animation. So it's just a workaround but as you said it returns immediately and that is not intended. The display method should open a window asking if the user wants to restart the game and then wait for the choice of yes button or no button.the button returns boolean value and based on that I wanna do some reaction like resetting everything

Comment: Then you should move the code that reacts to the user's choice into the `runLater` call as well.